# How to get the identity value in Entity Framework during SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I've a base table and dependent tables, and other tables. EF 4.0 (using MS VS 2010 Ultimate) performs fine when a base table's identity value is mapped to dependent tables because of foreign key relationship. What I expect a bit more, is that, the same identity value should be mapped/copied to a column in unassociated/not related table which tracks key/value pair. For instance, if the base table's first record identity is generated as 1, I want this number to be copied into that key/value table. 
When I tried, it's inserting as only 0 during SaveChanges() context in entity framework. This particular column is mapped to base table's column's identity property. It goes like,

> ```
> BaseTable baseTable = new BaseTable();
> // Added properties of basetable values
> KeyValueTable table = new KeyValueTable();
> table.Key = baseTable.BaseId;
> table.Value = name;
> AddToKeyValueTable(table);
> SaveChanges();
> ```

If I take a look into KeyValueTable, this key is written as 0 instead of the baseTable's generated value. I suspect this problem would be that these tables are not associated with a relationship. I shouldn't do so as the key could hold other tables as well.

Please assist me on this part.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the `value` from your desired *primary key* in that way because the [@@scope_identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) is not yet ready to `get`.

Try to do it like this

```
BaseTable baseTable = new BaseTable();
...
// Added properties of basetable values
SaveChanges();

KeyValueTable table = new KeyValueTable();
table.Key = baseTable.BaseId;
table.Value = name;
AddToKeyValueTable(table);
```